# Definition of holomorphic $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$-action on a complex manifold

Tags: lie-groups, holomorphic-functions, complex-manifolds

What is the definition of a holomorphic $\mathbb{C}^\ast$-action on a complex manifold $M$?

My understanding is that it is a group action of the Lie group $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ (the multiplicative group of complex numbers) on $M$ such that the map $ f: \mathbb{C}^\ast \times M \to M $ is holomorphic, which means that the map $ f $ from the complex manifold $ \mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times M $ (the Cartesian product of two complex manifolds is again a complex manifold) to $ M $ is holomorphic. That is, for all $ p \in \mathbb{C}^\ast \times M $ there is a chart $ (U, \phi) $ on $ \mathbb{C}^\ast \times M $ with $ p \in U $ and a chart $ (V, \psi) $ on $ M $ with $ \phi(p) \in V $ such that $ f(U) \subseteq V $ and the map $$
\phi(U) \stackrel{\phi^{-1}}\longrightarrow U \stackrel{f}{\to} V \stackrel{\psi}{\to}\mathbb{C}^n
$$ is holomorphic (it is a map from $\phi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ to $ \mathbb{C}^{n} $, where $ n $ is the dimension of $ M $, so $ n+1 $ is the dimension of $ \mathbb{C}^{\ast} \times M $).

Is my definition correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: An action $G\circlearrowright M$ of a Lie group in a manifold $M$ is a map $\varphi:G\times M\to M$ satisfying the usual properties from algebra. If $M$ is a complex manifold, you can say that the action is holomorphic if the partial map $\varphi_g:M\to M$ is holomorphic for all $g\in G$. Well... $\Bbb C^*$ is a Lie group with multiplication, so...

Comment: @IvoTerek is the definition that I gave equivalent to your definition?

Comment: I think your definition is a bit more restritive, since you want the full map to be holomorphic. I'm sure that these notions are equivalent if $M$ is "nice" (maybe compact or something like it)

Comment: @IvoTerek No restriction at all. The action you described is a bit more general, it could be given by any group homomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\ast \longrightarrow \mbox{Aut}(M)$. It will be "a holomomorphic action" if $\varphi_g$ depends holomorphically on $g$ falling in the OP's definition.